# How to generate UUID(Long) using cassandra timestamp in cluster environment?

Tags: cassandra, uuid

I have the requirement where we need to generate UUID as Long value using Java based on Cassandra timestamp which is in cluster. Can anyone help how to geranate it using java and cassandra cluster timestamp combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TimeUUID cql3 data type:

> A value of the timeuuid type is a Type 1 UUID. A type 1 UUID includes the time of its generation and are sorted by timestamp, making them ideal for use in applications requiring conflict-free timestamps. For example, you can use this type to identify a column (such as a blog entry) by its timestamp and allow multiple clients to write to the same partition key simultaneously. Collisions that would potentially overwrite data that was not intended to be overwritten cannot occur.

In Java you can use `UUIDs` helper class from `com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs`:

```
UUIDs.timeBased()
```

Comment: Can I use below code for generating unique long id generation across the application? this code may hit multiple clients at the same time.
UUID uuid = UUIDs.timeBased();
Long id = uuid.timestamp();

Can you please help me if we have any other option to generate UUID as long.

Comment: Time-based uuid contains of two parts (two Long values, not one!): timestamp and some node-dependent random bytes to prevent timestamp collisions. So TimeUUID is the best choice to generate unique timestamps in a distributed environment: collision probability is very very low.

Comment: Can you please share TimeUUID api for generating unique timestamps?

Comment: Sorry, I thought TimeUUID is api class :) Will use the same. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to generate a type 1 UUID from a epoch timestamp value ? Something like UUIDs.timeBased(epochTimeStamp) ?

Comment: @Yatin http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#startOf(long)

Comment: @Shutty The startOf and endOf would generate the same UUID when passed a same epochTimeStamp value. This is because the MSB part of that UUID is fake. That solution does not help in generating a TimeUUID which should be different based on same epochTimeStamp.